# Is the phrase "My circle of the people I know" correct?

Tags: phrase-usage, phrases, informal-language

I know a similar phrase which is "my circle of friends".

Thus, would this one apply as that phrase?

The sentence:

> Who could that be? Although **my circle of the people I know**, is not
>   that big.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Although my circle of the people I know, is not that big...

This is a little bit awkward because it says "my circle" and "I know" which is redundant. If it's your circle, you will know the people in it, right?

You could say:

> Although **the** circle of people I know is not that big...

but it is still a little wordy. You might want to say,

> Although **my** circle of **acquaintances** is not that big...

If you start your sentence with "although" I expect you to contrast your statement with something else after the comma. For example,

> Although my circle of friends is small, they come from places all over the world.

Comment: I would rewrite my sentence from "Who could that be? Although my circle of the people I know, is not that big. " to "Although my circle of acquaintances is not that big, I'm not sure who could that be." Thanks a lot.